# UITabBarController in UISplitViewController with Storyboard

Tags: uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller, uistoryboard, uisplitviewcontroller, uistoryboardsegue

I have `UISplitViewController` with `UITabBarController` as its master. `UITabBarController` contains one `UINavigationController` with `UITableViewController` as its root (it is **main menu** of my app).

After tapping on any cell in **main menu**, in `UISplitViewController`'s detail part another `UITableViewController` should be presented (let's call it **detail view**).

[image: storyboardscheme]

In landscape mode everything works OK.

But in portrait, whet I tap on cell in **main menu**, the **detail view** is presented modally, and not pushed, like it supposed to. Also, when rotating from landscape to portrait, the **main menu** is presented instead of **detail view**, and after I click on **main menu**'s position to show **detail view**, it is presented modally with no possibility to rotate or to go back.

Removing `UITabBarController` and setting `UINavigationController` as `UISplitViewController`'s master works as I want (in landscape mode we have **menu**|**detail** views side by side and in portrait mode controllers behave like they were on regular `UINavigationController`). But then the `UITabBarController` is gone.

*What I've tried:*

- every possible segue type - none of them works the way I want
- subclassing `UIStoryboardSegue` to implement custom behavior depending on `UISplitViewController`'s `viewControllers` param (in portrait mode it has only **one** view controller - master) - but I couldn't recognise classes (thank you Swift!)

What I want is to do it entirely in Storyboard (OK, custom segues doesn't count) - I want an elegant solution and I refuse to believe it's impossible.

Working on iOS 8 SDK, Xcode 6.2, iPhone 6 Plus

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no *absolutely elegant* solution to this one (as far as I've managed to accomplish). Hoping that Apple will eventually sort it out, but in the meantime, this is the *nicest way possible*:

- Place one custom segue instead of ***Show Detail***
- In `perform` method of your custom segue have something like:

```c
- (void)perform
{
    MasterViewController *source = self.sourceViewController;

    AppDelegate *appDelegate = [UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
    UISplitViewController *splitViewController = appDelegate.splitViewController;
    if ([splitViewController.viewControllers count] > 1) {
        [source performSegueWithIdentifier:@"showDetail" sender:source];
        if (appDelegate.masterPopoverController) {
            [appDelegate.masterPopoverController dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];
        }
    } else {
        [source performSegueWithIdentifier:@"showDetailSmallDevice" sender:source];
    }
}
```

- `[splitViewController.viewControllers count]` is here just to separate *large* devices (iPads & iPhone 6 Plus) and the other, *smaller* ones
- In your Storyboard, wire up one segue named `showDetail` which is actually a ***showDetail***, to the detail navigation controller, and directly to the contents view controller another `showDetailSmallDevice` which is actually ***Show 
  (Push)***

See the example:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/GQpg3.png

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:** `SplitViewController` needs two Navigation Controllers. The solution is that you need to insert another Navigation Controller between the `SplitViewController` and the `DatailViewController`. Then, from the `TableView`, preform a Segue directly to the second Navigation Controller. The `SplitViewControllers` wants two Navigation Controllers...

Maybe a good way could be to start a new `SplitViewController` project on IB. There are various default methods and properties to manage a `SplitViewController`. You can find something in appDelegate class, it could be a good starting point.

OLD: I like Mateusz's answer, just a point that is possible to  use `self.splitViewController.isCollapsed` for testing if `DetailViewController` is or it could be shown on screen. With this property there is no need to count viewControllers.

```
@property(nonatomic, readonly, getter=isCollapsed) BOOL collapsed
```

From documentation: A Boolean value indicating whether only one of the child view controllers is displayed. This property is set to YES when the split view controller content is semantically collapsed into a single container. Collapsing happens when the split view controller transitions from a horizontally regular to a horizontally compact environment. After it has been collapsed, the split view controller reports having only one child view controller in its viewControllers property.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: @Brody You are right! The solution is that he needs to insert another Navigation Controller between the SplitViewController and the DatailViewController. Than, from the TableView, preform a Segue directly to the second Navigation Controller. The SplitViewControllers wants two Navigation Controllers...

Comment: if it is about code, and coders talking to coders, it usually is much easier to use code directly, then to write about the code in natural language style. also, make your answer as short and precise as possible, as otherwise you just waste peoples reading time. remove useless information (non answer part, for example), or delete your answer entirely, if it does not add something valuable to the issue.

Comment: @Manos Thanks for the improved text style!